# Jquery autocomplete with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have strange problem:

First I have this code:

```
var countries = dajjson();

$('#usluga').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.ID + ', ' + suggestion.naziv);
    }
});
});

function dajjson() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "autoUsluge.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true, 
        dataType: "html",

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);   
        }, 
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log('GRESKA NEKA');
        }
    });
};
```

My JSON is - function DAJJSON() return:

```
[{"ID":"4","naziv":"","opis":"Web dizajn","jmere":"komada","kol":"2","cena":"50","valuta":"Eur","popust":"5","porez":"20","user_id":"1"},{"ID":"5","naziv":"","opis":"Programiranje","jmere":"sati","kol":"5","cena":"10","valuta":"Eur","popust":"5","porez":"20","user_id":"1"},{"ID":"6","naziv":"","opis":"Popravka zadnjeg trapa na automobilu Audi","jmere":"komada","kol":"1","cena":"80","valuta":"Eur","popust":"5","porez":"20","user_id":"1"}]
```

and where I test the code I just get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: `POST` is the wrong http action for not submitting data...you likely want to use a `GET`.  This is simply to follow the HTTP specification.

Comment: @abc123 I had to interact with Oracle Application Express in a previous job and the only requests it would allow were `POST`.  I agree with you - follow the spec whenever and wherever.. when it's not possible, it can be an absolute nightmare..

Answer (score 2):

Open up developer tools in whatever browser you're using (usually F12 or Ctrl-Shift-I or in the menus somewhere).  Click the "Network" tab and run your code.

Look at the response to your AJAX request.  It won't be what you're expecting :)

The `dataType` property you're passing to AJAX tells the server what kind of data you're expecting.  You have it set as `html`, so your response will be in HTML.  By the looks of it, you really want `json`.

Comment: maybe JSON is problem becouse I need in this format: var countries = [
    { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
    // ...
    { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
];